# Dynamically access image in react

Tags: reactjs, svg, import

I am importing an image to use later like so
`import S1 from '../../assets/images/S1.svg';`

I am then mapping through an array and want to access this import dynamically. How can I do this successfully?

loop is here:

```
{characteristics.map(characteristic => (
          <div className="characteristic" key={characteristic.key}>
            <span className="characteristicKey"><img src={characteristic.key} alt={characteristic.label} /></span>
            <span className="characteristicLabel">{characteristic.label}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a related name to file with characteristics for example c1.svg , c2.svg , c3.svg ...

then in your map :

```js
{characteristics.map((characteristic,i) => (
          <div className="characteristic" key={characteristic.key}>
            <span className="characteristicKey"><img src={require("c"+i+1+".svg")} alt={characteristic.label} /></span>
            <span className="characteristicLabel">{characteristic.label}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i cant hardcode "c" like that. The name of the key could be anything too so i cant use an index either